# iOS Auto Layout and constraint issue

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have built ios app layout on **compact width** and **regular height** because of the initial requirement of client but now the requirement has changed and he wants to deploy app on iphone and ipad both. So is it possible to update my constraint to **any width** and **any height** from compact width and regular height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain what krishnanunni is saying in a little more depth, what you need to do is first select the constraints you want to change. You can select multiple by shift clicking or command clicking them.

[image]

Then on the attributes or size inspector, you should see that the constraint is currently only installed for compact width, regular height (wC hR).

[image]

You need to check the checkbox that doesn't list a specific size class because
that refers to any width, any height. After that, there is no longer a need for the compact width, regular height constraint so you can delete it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help :) 

Just wants to make it little more clear for anyone who is in same issue that after "check the checkbox that doesn't list a specific size class because that refers to any width, any height. After that, there is no longer a need for the compact width, regular height constraint so you **should** delete it", because if you won't delete it and it would remain there unchecked, xcode will not consider constraints in that size class and your layout will not be work as expected on that size.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaSiddiqui - Interesting. Thanks for the follow up! Make sure to upvote answers that helped and accept the best one.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaSiddiqui, sounds good! I just noticed you hadn't accepted one of the answers so I was making sure you knew you could. That will help future readers know which answer solved your issue in case they have the same issue. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can install the same constraints in any-any.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

All your constraints would be placed for size class **compact width** and **regular height**, if you click on any of the constraint it would show you constraint installed on size class **compact width** and **regular height** as shown below

[image]

just uncheck (or click on small cross) with **wC hR** and check upper box (which is for **wAny hAny** size class)

you will have to do that for all constraints